# hive on spark on amazon EMR

Tags: apache-spark, hive, amazon-emr

I tried following command on hive :

```
set hive.execution.engine=spark;
```

but getting error when I run any query after setting execution engine on amazon EMR:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/Iterable
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.spark.GenSparkProcContext.<init>(GenSparkProcContext.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.spark.SparkCompiler.generateTaskTree(SparkCompiler.java:328)
        at ---------------
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.Iterable
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at ---------------
```

I tried to copy jar from spark to hive path and spark conf files to hive conf , 
still getting error, any fix ?

Answer (score 1):

The spark related jars to be added in hive script to run the hive query in spark execution engine.

Please add the following lines in ***/usr/lib/hive/bin/hive***  script

```
for f in ${SPARK_HOME}/jars/*.jar; do
     CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:$f;
done
```

after this line

```
HIVE_LIB=${HIVE_HOME}/lib
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks
Ravi

Comment: I got the following error inserting the code after HIVE_LIB 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SPARK_RPC_SERVER_ADDRESS
 at org.apache.hive.spark.client.rpc.RpcConfiguration.<clinit>(RpcConfiguration.java:47)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.HiveSparkClientFactory.initiateSparkConf(HiveSparkClientFactory.java:138)

Comment: Also when I echo SPARK_HOME, I get nothing, I had to manually export it as /usr/lib/spark, I am in AWS EMR master node with ec2-user

Comment: And the version of hive on `sudo -u hdfs hive --version` is
Hive 1.2.1-spark2-amzn-0
And the version of SPARK is 2.3 and Scala is 2.11 so this hive on EMR can't run on spark due to version incompatibility. Why is hive on 1.2 when hive 2 is out for so long?

Comment: This doesn't work. I'm getting an error after adding the above changes,

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SPARK_RPC_SERVER_ADDRESS

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to copy jar from spark to hive path and spark conf files to hive conf

You shouldn't need to do any sort of manual configuration. Did you install any components manually? I just created an EMR cluster with Hive, Spark and Hadoop and the command worked out of the box.

While creating the cluster, you need to to click on 'Go to advanced options' and check the components manually. The Spark stack in 'Quick Options' doesn't include Hive.

Comment: set hive.execution.engine=spark; this cmd works fine , but when i am querying anything from table like select count(*) from tableName, its giving error.